# New `fileExporter(isPresented:item:contentTypes:defaultFilename:onCompletion:onCancellation:)` leads to crash when item is `Image`

Tags: swiftui

I am on Xcode 15 Beta 5 and trying out the new `fileExporter(isPresented:item:contentTypes:defaultFilename:onCompletion:onCancellation:)` modifier where `item` needs to conform to `Transferable?` according to the documentation. This was added for macOS 15/iOS 17 and is still in beta.

I have the need to export an image of a `View` rendered from `ImageRenderer`.
The rendering part works and I can get an `Image` quite fine.

In the exporting view, I set the `@State` variables to trigger showing the export sheet with above mentioned modifier, but that results in an error in a subroutine: `Thread 2: EXC_BREAKPOINT (code=1, subcode=0x1be1c0050)`

Before I file feedback: has anyone been able to make this work? Am I totally wrong in my interpretation that I can `Image` (as it conforms to `Transferable`) here?

Or is this really a bug of this newly added overload func of `fileExporter` in the beta that I should file a feedback for?

Here's all the code:

```swift
import SwiftUI

@main
struct fb_fileExporterTransferableApp: App {
    var body: some Scene {
        WindowGroup {
            ContentView()
        }
    }
}

struct ContentView: View {
    @State private var isExporting = false
    @State private var exportingImage: Image?
    
    var body: some View {
        NavigationStack {
            VStack {
                Image(systemName: "globe")
                    .imageScale(.large)
                    .foregroundStyle(.tint)
                Text("Hello, world!")
            }
            .toolbar {
                ToolbarItem(placement: .automatic) {
                    Button {
                        if let exportingImage = createViewImage() {
                            isExporting = true
                            self.exportingImage = exportingImage
                        }
                    } label: {
                        Image(systemName: "square.and.arrow.up")
                    }
                }
            }
            .padding()
        }
        .fileExporter(isPresented: $isExporting, item: exportingImage) { result in
            switch result {
            case .success(let url):
                print("Exported successfully to \(url.absoluteString)")
            case .failure(let error):
                print("Could not export due to error: \(error.localizedDescription)")
            }
        }
    }
    
    @MainActor func createViewImage() -> Image? {
        let renderer = ImageRenderer(content: SomeView())
        if let uiImage = renderer.uiImage {
            return Image(uiImage: uiImage)
        }
        return nil
    }
}

#Preview {
    ContentView()
}

struct SomeView: View {
    var body: some View {
        VStack {
            Image(systemName: "globe")
                .imageScale(.large)
                .foregroundStyle(.tint)
            Text("Hello, world!")
        }
    }
}
```